# What is the relationship between the Wolfram executables? Where is this documented?

Tags: core-language, binary

The relatively new [`wolframscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) now accompanies the traditional `math` and [`wolfram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolfram.html) binaries. I am guessing (?) that `math` is effectively a deprecated alias for `wolfram`, since I can no longer find documentation for `math` and the binaries are the same size. So I will focus on `wolfram` vs `wolframscript`.

It looks to me (from the documentation linked above) that `wolframscript` offers a superset of the capabilities of `wolfram`. The only comparison I truly care about right now is `wolframscript -file file` vs `wolfram -script file` (and for systems where they differ, such as Windows, `WolframKernel -script file`). Are these essentially identical? As one example, is there any significance to the fact that the `wolframscript` documentation does not refer to "script mode" but the `wolfram` documentation does? (My presumption is no, but I hate to rely on presumption.)

Finally, does any of this link to file naming conventions. It seems that the extensions `.m`, `.wl`, and `.wls` all remain in use, and this use appears inconsistent in the documentation. As a striking example, the ["Code from a File" example for `wolfram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolfram.html) literally mixes up whether the example is working with `file.wls` or `test.wl`. What is the semantic information that is intended by the different extensions, if any? (My presumption is that `.wls` should be reserved for files that are made executable on a platform, but I hate to rely on presumption.)

I am very interested in educated guesses by experienced users, but obviously, pinning this down in the documentation would be ideal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`math`/`wolfram`, `MathKernel`/`WolframKernel` are all the same: they are the Mathematica kernel.  There is a difference between `math` and `MathKernel` on Windows in that the former is a console application (i.e. uses the standard terminal) while the latter is a GUI application, but otherwise they are the same thing.

`Mathematica`/`mathematica` is the front end.

[`wolframscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) is not the same thing as `math`/`wolfram`. It has different capabilities and it takes different command line options. It invokes `math`/`wolfram` in the background. It is also a separate program from Mathematica: you may have several Mathematica installations (e.g. multiple versions), but normally there is only a single `wolframscript`, which can be configured to use a certain Mathematica.

---

I believe that `wolframscript -file foo.m` and `wolfram -script foo.m` are *practically* equivalent for most purposes, but there are definitely some differences, and they are not indistinguishable.

For example, `$ScriptInputString` and `$ScriptCommandLine` work only with `wolframscript`. If examining variables related to (batch) input or output (such as `$Input` or `$Output`), there will also be differences. I expect these won't affect most scripts.

Personally I still use `wolfram -script` due to its predictability, and have little experience with `wolframscript`. `wolframscript` might not invoke the Mathematica kernel I expect when I use it on our HPC cluster with multiple Mathematica installations. `wolframscript` has also evolved rapidly, and not everything in its documentation is accurate. For example, one documentation example seems to show that with `-file`, it returns the result of the last command in the file, but this is not the case unless `-print` is also provided.

Comment: One other thing: if I recall correctly, it's a little easier to use `wolframscript` in a hashbang (like `#!/usr/env wolframscript` than it is `wolfram -script`, because the semantics of the hashbang can mess up when you pass arguments to it.

Comment: Thanks! According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolfram.html), `$ScriptCommandLine` does currently work with `wolfram`.